# Game about a squire who progresses to a knight while fighting a dragon and enemy soldiers in an over-world

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I can't remember the name of a single player CD-ROM game I played on PC 10+ years ago, when I was a child. The main protagonist started as a squire then progressed to a knight. There was an over world you could move around in, and a dragon would sometimes fly and breathe fire which would damage you. There were a number of enemy soldiers on the over-world, if you met one it would initiate a battle. There were wizards towers where you could buy potions, these included protection from dragon fire. You went around doing tasks and playing minigames. As the game progressed you received better armor and weapons. You were slowly given various mounts. These included a horse that could jump, a vehicle that could punch through hills, a "magical carriage" (I think), and a "flying tiger" (I think). There were a number of enemy henchman, who if you defeated you received their shield. One of the minigames was pushing away ladders from enemies who were trying to storm a castle. Another was using a cannon against a castle with its own cannons.

There was a castle building mode, where you got to build your own castle using tiled you got over the game. (You couldn't anything more then simply make it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [*Battle Castle*](https://www.mobygames.com/game/imaginext-battle-castle) from imaginext.

> The story starts with Dragomont, the game's baddie, releasing a mighty
> dragon from its prison and recruiting an army of orcs and knights to
> try and conquer the kingdom of Kingsland. The king is old and can no
> longer protect his people so he has decreed that whoever can vanquish
> the threat can take the crown.
>
> [image]

### Gameplay